# How to make a mvc html field disabled?

Tags: spring-roo

I have a create.html form that has fields generated from my spring roo 2.0 domain model:

```html
<div class="form-group has-error has-feedback" data-z="790e58b4" id="consultation-prediction-field" data-th-classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('prediction')}? 'has-error has-feedback'" data-th-class="form-group">
  <label for="prediction" class="col-md-3 control-label" data-th-text="#{label_consultation_prediction}">prediction</label>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <input id="prediction" name="prediction" data-th-value="*{{prediction}}" type="text" class="form-control inputmask" placeholder="prediction" data-th-placeholder="#{label_consultation_prediction}" data-toggle="tooltip" aria-describedby="predictionStatus" data-inputmask-alias="numeric" data-inputmask-digits="2" />
      <span data-th-classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('prediction')}? 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback" data-th-if="${#fields.hasErrors('prediction')}" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span id="prediction-error" class="help-block" data-th-if="${#fields.hasErrors('prediction')}" data-th-errors="*{prediction}">Error message.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to disable the field in the UI.  I have tried to add a `disabled` attribute to the `input` field definition:

```html
<div class="form-group has-error has-feedback" data-z="790e58b4" id="consultation-prediction-field" data-th-classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('prediction')}? 'has-error has-feedback'" data-th-class="form-group">
  <label for="prediction" class="col-md-3 control-label" data-th-text="#{label_consultation_prediction}">prediction</label>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <input id="prediction" name="prediction" disabled data-th-value="*{{prediction}}" type="text" class="form-control inputmask" placeholder="prediction" data-th-placeholder="#{label_consultation_prediction}" data-toggle="tooltip" aria-describedby="predictionStatus" data-inputmask-alias="numeric" data-inputmask-digits="2" />
      <span data-th-classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('prediction')}? 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback" data-th-if="${#fields.hasErrors('prediction')}" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span id="prediction-error" class="help-block" data-th-if="${#fields.hasErrors('prediction')}" data-th-errors="*{prediction}">Error message.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

This works temporarily, but spring roo removes this `disabled` attribute when it regenerates the form.

How can I permanently set this attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that I just need to set the attribute:

```
data-z="user-managed"
```

In the `form-group` for the field.